# Latex multiple tables with different colors and header alignment

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I am trying to have different tables in my report. Some of them I need to have the headers one color (black with white text) and different rowcolor (Table 1).

While others I need only the headers to be coloured and that to be centered.

I have added my current code to [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/prdqtndjtnjr)  and adding an image to what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. The cells contents were already centred, so there was nothing to do. Note `hyperref` should be loaded as the last package, with very few exceptions (`cleveref` is such an exception).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%** latex setup**%
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} %for fitting the tables
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!15}{white}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{quotchap}
\usepackage[nottoc,notindex,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}
\definecolor{LightCyan}{rgb}{0.88,1,1}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}            % For drawing stuff
\usepackage{glossaries}      % For abbrevations 
\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{hyperref} %For adding hyperlinks

%** new commands**%
\newcommand{\head}[1]{%
    \textcolor{white}{\textbf{#1}}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\renewcommand*{\sectfont}{\bfseries}


\title{Table Formating}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Table 1}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \sffamily
    \caption{Table variant 1} \label{tb:1}
\begin{tabular}{|cccc|}
    \rowcolor{black!75}
    \head{\#} & \head{Layer Name }& \head{Cooper Thickness} & \head{Description} \\ 
    1 & Top Solder Mask &  & Solder Resist \\ 
    \hline 
    2 & Top Layer & 1.4 mil &  \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\section{Table Formating}


\begin{table}[!h]
    \centering
    \sffamily
\rowcolors{3}{}{}
    \caption{Table 2} \label{tb:2}
\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \rowcolor{black!75}
    \head{PARAMETER} & \head{SPECIFICATIONS / COMMENTS }\\ 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\cellcolor{black!60}\head{TEMPERATURE SENSOR}} \\
    \hline 
    Sensor & ... \\ 
    \hline 
    Pressure sensor &  \\ 
    \hline 
    Name ... & ... \\ 
    \hline 
    Resolution & ...  \\ 
    \hline 
    Accelometer and Magnometer &  \\ 

\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code doesn't produce the table you showed as table 2. With your code, table 2 still has striped rows.

It will work if you insert the following after \begin{table}[!h]: 
\rowcolors{1}{white}{white}

Comment: @jaspast: Sorry, it was a clipboard accident. I copied the O.p.s code instead of mine. It's fixed (`\rowcolors...` just before `\begin{tabular}`. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: Hi, about centering. I would like the TEMPERATURE SENSOR to take the whole row and be centered. That's what I meant. Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Please see my updated code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bernard!